# Re-request Facebook permissions using oAuth does not work

Tags: facebook, oauth, permissions, request

I started a submission for two permissions (manage_pages and read_insights) and it has been approved. 
How can I re request the permissions now?

The thing is, that I already used the permissions in my web-app, but I was missing the changes on April 30. That means, my customers already accepted the permission before, but in case of the changes, they had been removed.

This is what my authentication code is looking like:

*https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={my appId}&redirect_uri={my redirectUri}&auth_type=rerequest&scope=user_friends,email,public_profile,manage_pages,read_insights*

This is not working at all... I was already using Fiddler to see what's going on and it says, that I declined the permissions. But I was not even able to accept them because I wasn`t asked.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs you need to add the `auth_type=rerequest` parameter to the request, as you already seem to do:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app-id}&
    redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&
    auth_type=rerequest&
    scope=user_friends,email,public_profile,manage_pages,read_insights
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#reaskperms

The behavior you experience might be because you didn't went through Login Review, which you need to do if you want to use the extended permissions in your app.

See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/…

Try with one of your app's admins/testers/developers and see if it works then.

Comment: By "it's not working at all" I mean, that I just get the regular login dialog to enter my password but it's not asking me to accept the permissions. 

Oh.. I forgot to mention, that I called the URL in the browser as well and it has the same behavior as in my web-app.

Comment: We did the Login Review already. The permission has been approved.